# Click an image to upload file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a react app where I need to click an image which will serve the purpose of a button to upload a file. I can not figure out how to use an image as an input button.

Comment: @StudioTime . That doesnt refer to the question, as this question is about a submit button (Which needs a form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to use a wrapper element and pure css for that. just put an image where the text is now.

```css
.wrapper{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative
}

.btnimg{
  background:red;
  pointer-events:none;
  width:250px;
  height:90px;
  opacity:1;
  line-height:90px;
  text-align:center;
}

input[type=file]{
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="btnimg">btn with image</div>
<input type="file">
</div>
```